# This aspect of the painting stems/stemmed from deceased Leonardo da Vinci's sexual orientation. - stems or stemmed?

Tags: tense, usage

**Example 1**

> ‎This aspect of the painting stems/stemmed from Leonardo da Vinci's sexual orientation.

**Example 2**

> This aspect of the painting stems/stemmed from deceased Leonardo da Vinci's sexual orientation.

Can Example 1 mean the same as Example 2?

Do we always have to add "deceased" to a name of a person that passed away?

If the person is dead, should the verb be in past tense of present tense?

Comment: Nobody needs to be reminded that da Vinci is dead. It's a stylistic choice whether to say [*Bach's music **reflects***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bach%27s+music+reflects%22) or [***reflected***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bach%27s+music+reflected%22) *[his sexual orientation, cultural background, or whatever]*.

Comment: We have no sexual orientation after death. The aspect is now analyzed, so we see now what it stems from, not stemmed.

Comment: How many people would actually need  reminding that da Vinci is not alive?? I did not see FF's comment. which goes to prove how bizarre and convoluted adding "deceased" is.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - 'We have no sexual orientation after death' - that's a big statement to make.

Comment: Also, when referring to a recently deceased person we say "the late Fred Bloggs".

Comment: It's a choice which to use, but you need to be consistent (and not keep switching without good reason).

Answer (score 1):

It is conventional to speak and write of art and literature in the present tense.

That said, when referring to something from the artist's life and its impact on one of their works of art, you could make that thing from their life the subject of your sentence and use a past-tense verb or a present perfect (*DaVinci's sexual orientation influenced how he ...* or *has shown itself in the way he ...*).  The expectation is a present-tense verb when the work or one of its elements is the subject, *qua* work of art (i.e. not in its historical context, e.g. a statue being transported from the workshop to the plaza).